# How to create jQuery function for replying nested commens in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, prepend

How to create//change my jQuery function in create.js.erb file for creating nested comments like in the sreenshot. While creation comment using Js from create.js.erb **helper method doesn't call**? How to fix that?

[image]
Comments_helper.rb

```
 module CommentsHelper
      def comments_tree_for(comments)
        comments.map do |comment, nested_comments|
          render(comment) +
              (nested_comments.size > 0 ? content_tag(:div, comments_tree_for(nested_comments), class: "replies") : nil)
        end.join.html_safe
      end
    end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Join the discussion</h1>
    <p>Click the button below to start a new thread:</p>
    <p>
      <%= link_to 'Add new topic', new_comment_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
    </p>
  </div>
    <%= comments_tree_for @comments %>
</div>
```

_commnet.html.erb

```
<div  id="comment-cont_<%= comment.id %>" class="well">
  <h2><%= comment.title %></h2>
  <p class="text-muted"><%= comment.root? ? "Started by" : "Replied by" %> <strong>Alex Petrov </strong> on
    <%= l(comment.created_at, format: '%B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S') %></p>

<% from_reply_form ||= nil %>
<% unless from_reply_form %>
  <% if comment.leaf? %>
    <small class="text-muted">There are no replies yet - be the first one to reply!</small>
  <% end %>

  <p><div id="reply-comment_<%= comment.id%>"><%= link_to 'reply', new_comment_path(comment.id), remote: true %></p></div>
<% end %>

</div>
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#reply-comment_<%= @comment.parent_id %>').hide();
$("#comment-cont_<%= @comment.id %>").prepend('<%= j render @comment %>');
```

Comment: margin-left:50%; (or any percentage) ~ You could say "each nest = 10%" so a comment "5 levels deep" would have 50% margin-left, but a comment on the top (0 levels deep / level 1) would be 0% margin-left (100% width), and then put a max on it so that a comment can never be too small

Comment: bootstrap nested comments (media-list) is also a great solution: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media-list

Comment: Yes, I did so. But when I click button create nothing happening( without reload page), but when I reload page elements dispose like on the Screenshot.

Comment: @Timothy94 how did you build your form, did you add `remote: true`?

Comment: @Sovalina Yes, with controller and action everything is OK. My problem with fronted-part. I can't right write jQuery function.